# convert text file separated by new line to csv file

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to convert a file like follows

```
hello
world
123

bye
world
456

byee
world
456678
```

to a csv file like

```
hello,world,123
bye,world,456
byee,world,456678
```

Is is possible to do this without iterating through the entire file and seeing for new line?

Comment: what I would do: `scan()` each section in, combine all sections, then write.csv(). There is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the multi.line capacity of `scan` and then write.table with appropriate parameters:

```
txt <- "hello
world
123

bye
world
456

byee
world
456678"
temp <- data.frame( scan(text=txt, 
                    what= list( word="", dest="", num=numeric(), "NULL"), 
                    multi.line=TRUE))
 write.table(temp, sep=",", file="", quote=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
#-------------
1,hello,world,123,
2,bye,world,456,
3,byee,world,456678,
```

Obviously you would use a legal file name if you wanted this sent to disk.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- readLines( # con = 'path/to/your/file'
   con = textConnection('hello
world
123

bye
world
456

byee
world
456678')

write.csv(
  t(matrix(
    dat[-seq(4,length(dat),4)], # Drop the spacer
    length(dat)/3,3), # Estimate columns
  file = "path/to/your.csv" 
  ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Scan it in, shape it into a 3 column matrix by row and write it out.  (Replace the first argument of `scan` and second argument of `write.table` with the input and output file names.)

```
m <- matrix(scan(textConnection(Lines), what = ""), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
write.table(m, stdout(), sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
hello,world,123
bye,world,456
byee,world,456678
```

**Note**

We used this as the input

```
Lines <- "hello
world
123

bye
world
456

byee
world
456678"
```